# Keep the $character in regular expression replace

Tags: regex, powershell

Two problems of regular replace

1.need to keep the front $character in the replacement result

2.Skipping the first two lines and the last line is not valid

Code:

```
$str = @'
#$start1 Random characters
#$start2 Random characters
$p1.AppendBreak($BreakType.LineBreak)
$doc.Protect($ProtectionType.AllowOnlyRevisions, "123")
$footerPara.AppendField("page", $FieldType.FieldPage)
$footerParagraph.AppendField("number of pages", $FieldType.FieldSectionPages)

$txtWatermark.Layout = $WatermarkLayout.Diagonal
$tr1.CharacterFormat.Border.BorderType = $BorderStyle.DashDotStroker
$stri.CharacterFormat.TextBackgroundColor = $Color.LightGray

$document.LoadFromFile(".\Template_HtmlFile.html", $FileFormat.Html, $XHTMLValidationType.None)

$docObject.DocumentObjectType -eq $DocumentObjectType.Picture

$document.Sections[0].Paragraphs[0].InsertSectionBreak($SectionBreakType.NoBreak)

$footerParagraph.Format.HorizontalAlignment = $Spire.Doc.Documents.HorizontalAlignment.Right
#end Random characters
'@

$str | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '\$\w+\.(\w+)', '"$1"'
} | Set-Content .\ok.txt

<# -Skip -SkipLast not valid
$str | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '\$\w+\.(\w+)', '"$1"'
} | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Set-Content .\ok.txt
#>
```

Expected results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for your example here string, you need to break it into a string array. Then for the replacement I was only successful when capturing both the beginning and the desired changed text.

```
$str -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -Skip 2 |
        Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Foreach-Object {
            $_ -replace '(^.+?)\$.+\.(\w+)', '$1"$2"'
        } | Set-Content .\ok.txt
```

Contents of ok.txt

```
$p1.AppendBreak("LineBreak")
$doc.Protect("AllowOnlyRevisions", "123")
$footerPara.AppendField("page", "FieldPage")
$footerParagraph.AppendField("number of pages", "FieldSectionPages")

$txtWatermark.Layout = "Diagonal"
$tr1.CharacterFormat.Border.BorderType = "DashDotStroker"
$stri.CharacterFormat.TextBackgroundColor = "LightGray"

$document.LoadFromFile(".\Template_HtmlFile.html", "None")

$docObject.DocumentObjectType -eq "Picture"

$document.Sections[0].Paragraphs[0].InsertSectionBreak("NoBreak")

$footerParagraph.Format.HorizontalAlignment = "Right"
```

Comment: thanks, I really want to know how to write a regular expression if the content is surrounded by characters @"……“@?

Comment: That is possible but it would be insanely ugly in this case. You’d have to account for all the new line characters. Or if you wanted to pull consistent info from *everyline* it would be easier. The fact that you wanted to skip 2 and last line meant we’d already need to make it multi line.

Comment: err【$document.LoadFromFile(".\Template_HtmlFile.html", "None")】right【$document.LoadFromFile(".\Template_HtmlFile, “html", "None")】

Comment: It's filtered out $FileFormat.Html Like the one above